# Plesk MySQL driver configuration error on CentOS

Tags: mysql, centos, driver, plesk

After manually upgrading PHP and MySQL on my Cent OS box then logging in to my Plesk administration panel, I'm receiving the following error when attempting to carry out numerous tasks. PHP and MySQL are functioning correctly in their own right.

```
New files of configuration for Apache web server were not built due to errors in configuration templates: Template processing failed: file = /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/default/domainVhost.php, error = [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/lib64/libmyodbc3.so' : /usr/lib64/libmyodbc3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. The detailed error message was e-mailed to you, so please check the e-mail, fix the errors, and click here to retry generating broken configuration or click here to retry generating of all configurations.
```

I have located the ODBC configuration details in the following file:

```
/etc/odbcinst.ini
```

The contents of which are as follows:

```
# Driver from the MyODBC package
# Setup from the unixODBC package
[MySQL]
Description = MySQL driver for Plesk
Driver      = /usr/lib64/libmyodbc3.so
Setup       =
FileUsage   = 1
Driver64    = /usr/lib64/libmyodbc3.so
Setup64     =
UsageCount  = 1
```

I expect that the Driver & Driver64 parameters must be updated to reflect the changes that occurred when MySQL was upgraded however I am unable to locate the path to the appropriate driver and am out of my depth now. Any advice greatly welcomed.

UPDATE: a '# locate libmyodbc3' returns no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the ODBC and mysql-connector-odbc packages were missing.

They were installed using YUM as follows:

```
 # yum install unixODBC 
 # yum mysql-connector-odbc packages
```